# Show percentage or some text in ProgressBar

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar

My program is a testing. When giving a correct answer, my `Progress Bar` is increased, but I want to show a percentage of correct answers. I use next code, that I found in the net:

```
progressBar1.PerformStep();

int percent = (int)(((double)progressBar1.Value /
                     (double)progressBar1.Maximum) * 100);

progressBar1.CreateGraphics().DrawString(
    percent.ToString() + "%",
    new Font("Arial", (float)8.25, FontStyle.Regular),
    Brushes.Black,
    new PointF(progressBar1.Width / 2 - 10, progressBar1.Height / 2 - 7));
```

I place this code in the `answer_but_click` event. `answer_but` is a button that checks your answer, define whether it is true or false and counts a general number of given correct answers. Percentage appears for a milisecond and thet disappers. What's the problem?

Comment: it's not duplicate. I use the same code as in the question that you give. My problem is that the text with percentage only blinks for miliseconds and disappears.

Comment: Sure it's a duplicate.  You simply ignored the highest reputation answer posted.  You should never use CreateGraphics since it's just a temporary drawing.